# Renovate with Google Cloud, Github, Python project, and pyproject.toml

Tags: python, github, google-cloud-platform, renovate

## High Level

I am trying to allow [Renovate](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate) to manage Python dependency updates, including updates dependent upon our own internal registry, which lives in [Google's Artifact Registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry). We use GitHub to manage our repositories, and Github's provision of Renovate.

## Details

To do this, I need to update the `renovate.json5` file to allow access to the repo. There is scant information in the documentation, and I have looked in the following places:

- [Private package support](https://docs.renovatebot.com/getting-started/private-packages/)
- [Python package manager support](https://docs.renovatebot.com/python/)
- [Renovate Git Issues filtered for `pyproject.toml`](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/issues?q=is%3Aissue+pyproject.toml)
- [Scant documentation on GCP](https://docs.renovatebot.com/presets-packages/#packagesgoogleapis)

and as far as I can tell, I am *supposed to add something like this* to get access to my private repo:

```json
{
  "hostRules": [
    {
      "matchHost": "https://registry.company.com/pypi-simple/",
      "username": "engineering",
      "password": "abc123"
    }
  ]
}
```

It *seems that* Renovate can *only* use username + password for Python packages.  However, I am using a service account, for which Google uses tokens (and other passwordless authentication means).  For example, to access the repo, I add the following to `pip.conf` (or to `[[tool.pdm.source]]` in my `pyproject.toml` since I am using PDM to build):

```
[global]
extra-index-url = https://_json_key_base64:<long_string_for_private_info>@us-west1-python.pkg.dev/my-project/my-repo/simple/
```

In the case of Google / GCP, that `<long_string_for_private_info>` is actually a base 64 encoded JSON blob with a bunch of information:

```bash
> echo <long_string_for_private_info> | base64 --decode
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "my-project",
  "private_key_id": "<filtered out for security>",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n<Filtered out for security>\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "my-service-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "<filtered out for security>",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/my-service-account%40my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
}
```

The filtered out private key is also base64 encoded (so that there is a base64 encoded object that after decoding, it has another base64 encoded object in it).

## Attempts so far

I have tried the following:

### Using a token:

```
{
  "matchHost": "us-west1-python.pkg.dev",
  "hostType": "pypi",
  "encrypted": {
    "token": <hidden for security>
  }
}
```

### Using a username and password:

```
{
  "matchHost": "us-west1-python.pkg.dev",
  "hostType": "pypi",
  "username": "_json_key_base64"
  "encrypted": {
    "password": <hidden for security>
  }
}
```

In each of the cases above (token or username/password), I have:

- Always encoded [using Renovate's encryption page](https://app.renovatebot.com/encrypt)
- Tried the *base64 encoded* version of just the `"private_key"` mentioned above
- Tried the *decoded* version of just the `"private_key"` mentioned above
- Tried the *base64 encoded* *entire* `"long_string_for_private_info"` object mentioned in the `extra-index-url` in `pip.conf`.

  - Remember that I am able to download (and upload) Python packages to the registry, so I know that `pip.conf` file is correct.
- Tried the *decoded* version of the entire `"long_string_for_private_info"`.

At this point, I have run out of ideas, and the documentation does not really explain how to use tokens with Python packages at all, let alone with Google's cloud infrastructure.

## Error Reported

No matter how the secret is seen, the error is always the same, a variant of:

```json
{
  "err": {
    "validationError": "Encrypted secret is scoped to a different repository: \"US-WEST1-PYTHON.PKG.DEV/MY-PROJ/MY-REPO\".",
    "message": "config-validation",
    "stack": "Error: config-validation\n    at tryDecrypt (/opt/containerbase/tools/renovate/36.83.0/node_modules/renovate/lib/config/decrypt.ts:124:31)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n    at decryptConfig (/opt/containerbase/tools/renovate/36.83.0/node_modules/renovate/lib/config/decrypt.ts:186:30)\n    at decryptConfig (/opt/containerbase/tools/renovate/36.83.0/node_modules/renovate/lib/config/decrypt.ts:238:13)\n    at mergeRenovateConfig (/opt/containerbase/tools/renovate/36.83.0/node_modules/renovate/lib/workers/repository/init/merge.ts:252:27)\n    at getRepoConfig (/opt/containerbase/tools/renovate/36.83.0/node_modules/renovate/lib/workers/repository/init/config.ts:12:12)\n    at initRepo (/opt/containerbase/tools/renovate/36.83.0/node_modules/renovate/lib/workers/repository/init/index.ts:44:12)\n    at Object.renovateRepository (/opt/containerbase/tools/renovate/36.83.0/node_modules/renovate/lib/workers/repository/index.ts:55:14)\n    at attributes.repository (/opt/containerbase/tools/renovate/36.83.0/node_modules/renovate/lib/workers/global/index.ts:184:11)\n    at start (/opt/containerbase/tools/renovate/36.83.0/node_modules/renovate/lib/workers/global/index.ts:169:7)\n    at /opt/containerbase/tools/renovate/36.83.0/node_modules/renovate/lib/renovate.ts:18:22"

.
.
.

{
  "error": {
    "validationError": "Failed to decrypt field token. Please re-encrypt and try again.",
    "message": "config-validation",
    "stack": "Error: config-validation\n    at decryptConfig (/opt/containerbase/tools/renovate/36.83.0/node_modules/renovate/lib/config/decrypt.ts:192:27)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)\n    at decryptConfig (/opt/containerbase/tools/renovate/36.83.0/node_modules/renovate/lib/config/decrypt.ts:238:13)\n    at mergeRenovateConfig (/opt/containerbase/tools/renovate/36.83.0/node_modules/renovate/lib/workers/repository/init/merge.ts:252:27)\n    at getRepoConfig (/opt/containerbase/tools/renovate/36.83.0/node_modules/renovate/lib/workers/repository/init/config.ts:12:12)\n    at initRepo (/opt/containerbase/tools/renovate/36.83.0/node_modules/renovate/lib/workers/repository/init/index.ts:44:12)\n    at Object.renovateRepository (/opt/containerbase/tools/renovate/36.83.0/node_modules/renovate/lib/workers/repository/index.ts:55:14)\n    at attributes.repository (/opt/containerbase/tools/renovate/36.83.0/node_modules/renovate/lib/workers/global/index.ts:184:11)\n    at start (/opt/containerbase/tools/renovate/36.83.0/node_modules/renovate/lib/workers/global/index.ts:169:7)\n    at /opt/containerbase/tools/renovate/36.83.0/node_modules/renovate/lib/renovate.ts:18:22"
  }
}
```

I have even inspected those two functions on Renovate's github repo, but they are very "introspective" and javascript is not my best language, so I could not get too far.

Answer (score 2):

I actually did get this to work eventually, as I [describe in Renovate's GitHub](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/discussions/24326#discussioncomment-6967191).

But I was only able to get things to work if I *did not encrypt* the password.

#### The following worked in the `renovate.json5` file:

```json
"hostRules": [
    {
       "matchHost": "us-west1-python.pkg.dev",
      "hostType": "pypi",
      "username": "_json_key_base64",
      "password": "<filtered for security>"
    }
]
```

#### And the following *did not* work:

```json
"hostRules": [
    {
        "matchHost": "us-west1-python.pkg.dev",
        "hostType": "pypi",
        "username": "_json_key_base64",
        "encrypted": {
            "password": <the encrypted value spit out by using mend renovate>
        }
    }
]
```

The reference to Mend Renovate is to [this site](https://app.renovatebot.com/encrypt).

---

At this point, I *think* it might be a bug. But I'm still not convinced. Regardless, I can get this to work with the *unencrypted* base64 "password", but I cannot get it to work after encryption.

I *suspect* this is because Google's Artifact Registry does not just use a simple password, but it sends a relatively complex object. But I am not confident of this, and still looking for some help if anyone knows better, or if anyone can test it out and get things to work.

Comment: I struggled with this one, even after researching it. I didn't expect it to work with an unencrypted password, that surprised me.